# Why is true greater than 3 in PHP

Tags: php, types, casting

I am wondering why following statement in PHP is returning true?

```
true>=4
```

for example such line will echo `1`

```
echo true>=4;
```

Can anyone explain me the logic behind this?

Comment: The integer 4 is being converted to a boolean type before comparison.  All non-zero integers convert to boolean value TRUE.  If you try `true >= 0` you'll see that it's also true, because `true > false`.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: Sidenote regarding the question title 'Why is true greater than 3'. It's not. Its EQUAL to 3.  And of course, the question refers to 4.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to Davids answer, I thought to add something to give a little more depth.

PHP unlike other programming languages, if your not careful with your operators/syntax you can fall into tricky pot holes like the one you experience.

As David said,

> 4 is also true (because it's non-zero), and true is equal to true, so
>   it's also greater than or equal to true.

Take this into account
*True is greater than false.*

true = 1

false = 0

So take this for example:

```
$test = 1;
if ($test == true){
echo "This is true"; 
}else{
echo "This is false";
}
```

The above will output

> This is true

But if you take this:

```
$test = 1;
if ($test === true){
echo "This is true"; 
}else{
echo "This is false";
}
```

The above will output:

> This is false

The added equals sign, looks for an exact match, thus looking for the `integer` **1** instead of PHP reading 1 as true.

**I know this is a little off topic, but just wanted to explain some pot holes which PHP contains.**

**I hope this is some help**

Edit:

In response to your question:

> echo true>=4;

Reason you are seeing 1 as output, is because true/false is interpreted as numbers (see above)

Regardless if your doing `echo true>=4` or just `echo true;` php puts true as 1 and false as 0

Comment: +1. I really like this answer. It includes a good explanation that expands on the original question.  It's also aimed at a beginner which the OP probably is. Nice!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for and I completely forgot about ===. BTW I think you meant "This is false" in second example.

Comment: And according to the docs true/false(bool) is not treated as numbers rather the second operand is converted to bool(in this case 4 => true) "Convert to bool, FALSE < TRUE" - php.net

Answer (score 21):

`4` is also `true` (because it's non-zero), and `true` is equal to `true`, so it's also greater than or equal to `true`.

If a bool or null is compared to anything other than a string, that thing is cast to a bool. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: So the number is cast to boolean rather than vice versa... What an amazing language...

Comment: Yep. You got it. If a bool or null is compared to anything other than a string, that thing is cast to a bool. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: @JanDvorak that's PHP for ya!

Comment: I see this answer has received many upvotes, but to me it doesn't actually explain WHY... The explanation comes in the comments; that it casts to a bool. Shouldn't that be part of the answer?

Comment: @JonathanSpiller: I added it. But I can't imagine anyone who wouldn't understand that the first part of my answer is saying that it's cast a bool.