# Cant login: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli

I have a login script that doesn't work anymore. It has something to do with the new mysqli.
So I changed mysql query to mysqli but still get errors:

```
if (empty($errors)){
    $query = "SELECT id, username ";
    $query .= "FROM users ";
    $query .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
    $query .= "AND hashed_password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($query);
    confirm_query($result_set);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) == 1){
        $found_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $found_user['username'];
        redirect_to("faculty.php");
    } else {
        $message = " Username / Password is incorrect.";
    }
```

That is my code, `mysqli_query($query);` is the problem. When I change it to `mysqli_query($connection , $query);`, I don't get the error anymore but I get the message:

> Username / Password is incorrect.

When it is correct.

My connection script:

```
<?php
require("constants.php");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if (!$connection){
    die("Unable to connect to page");   
}

?>

<?php
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection , "fm_cms");
if (!$db){
    die("Unable to connect to Database");   
}
?>

<?php
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection , "fm_cms");
if (!$db){
    die("Unable to connect to Database");   
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you specified values for $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);  ?

Comment: at file constants.php

Comment: Instead of redirect_to("faculty.php"); try redirect_to("Location:faculty.php");

Comment: but thats only until login succeeds right ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQLI requires both the connection and the query in the parameters.

```
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Full practical:

```
$Con = mysqli_connect(/* Connection Information here*/);
$Result_Set = mysqli_query($Con,"SELECT ID FROM table");
```

---

In response to your updated question body, the `mysqli_select_db` is to be used when one wishes to change the current working schema (database). In this case, originally connecting to the schema specified in the constant `DB_NAME`. If you are not wanting to swap schemas but keep the same. Then remove the `mysqli_select_db`

and a working MySQLi Query construct would be:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$Query = mysqli_query($connection,"QUERY HERE");
if (!$connection){
    die("Unable to connect to page");   
}
```

and in response to; *i dont get the error anymore but i get the message: Username / Password is incorrect. when it is correct.. Help please!*

You are being presented this message because you have told PHP to do so, as your `mysqli_num_rows` is returning false (due to a incorrect `mysqli_query` being supplied) the numbered rows will **not** be equal to 1, but be interpreted as **0** ([Possible Refence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711945/why-is-true-greater-than-3-in-php/13712148#13712148))

[MySQLi Query Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: i tried this but then i cant login and i get the message Username / Password is incorrect.. so it must do something wrong

Comment: if i use $Result_Set = mysqli_query($Con,"SELECT ID FROM table"); i get error Unable to connect

Comment: @Brutalized Please update this code into your question body so I can check correctly

Comment: @Brutalized What does not work? also, is `confirm_query` a function which you have written yourself?. You need to be more specific, I can safely say what I have provided will work